# Sitecore JSS next.js headless Experience Editor not working in html mode

Tags: jss, experience-editor, nextjs

I'm facing the issue that Experience Editor is loading with components, ribbon and all kind of stuff. Components are selectable but no interaction in ribbon is working whenever I would expect some Modal Dialog like: add component, Presentation Details, Switch Language and so on.

The request for that are sent and I receive 200 status codes with data of the dialogs eg: add component) but nothing is displayed and no console errors appear.
In Horizon everything works fine, there I'm able to add components etc.

Are there any ideas what could be wrong.

The page itself is really simple only the Sitecore JSS layout with a next.js Layout.tsx which have the three placeholders jss-header jss-main jss-footer. But even here I have the problem behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it takes a lot of time during opening a dialog first time in Experience Editor due to MVC component precompilation. It requires warming up and then it will work much faster.